# Mentions in slack ephemeral message do not trigger mobile notifications

Tags: python-3.x, slack-api

I am working on a slack bot.

This bot posts ephemerals messages to let the users know it's time to do some actions.

The ephemeral message contains a mention of the user (<@user_id>) so that the user should be notified.

The notification is triggered on computer but not on mobile.

Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

No its not. Ephemeral message delivery is not guaranteed — the user must be currently active in Slack and a member of the specified channel. By nature, ephemeral messages do not persist across reloads, desktop and mobile apps, or sessions.You can find more info [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral)